# Error 1064 in MySQL Workbench when synchronising a model to a server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to MySQL and have only used Microsoft Access before for SQL. When I try to add the Model to the server ([Database]->[Synchronize Model]), the auto-generated SQL code throws this error

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near ')

REFERENCES `medicineproblems`.`SleepTimes` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ' at line 7
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `medicineproblems`.`Records` (
          `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
          `SleepDuration` DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          `MoodAverage` DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          PRIMARY KEY (`Date`),
          CONSTRAINT `SleepDuration`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `medicineproblems`.`SleepTimes` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `MoodAverage`
            FOREIGN KEY ()
            REFERENCES `medicineproblems`.`Mood` ()
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
        DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I want to be able to know what went wrong. So in your answers, can you please tell me possible causes of the error so I can aim to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the column name to reference on that table as well as the column which will be referring to and thus the error is pointing about. The below line

```
        FOREIGN KEY ()
        REFERENCES `medicineproblems`.`SleepTimes` ()
```

Should be

```
FOREIGN KEY(some_column_name)
REFERENCES `medicineproblems`.`SleepTimes`(some_column_name)
```

Similarly you should correct this in the below part of your `CREATE TABLE` syntax

```
      CONSTRAINT `MoodAverage`
        FOREIGN KEY ()
        REFERENCES `medicineproblems`.`Mood` ()
```

See [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for more information. Correct syntax is:

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
    [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
    REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [ON DELETE reference_option]
    [ON UPDATE reference_option]
```

Comment: Thank you. You'd think there would be a warning or something if a column name is omitted.

Comment: @JamesYeoman There was. It's expecting a name after `(`, but it got `)` instead, so it says there's a syntax error there.

Comment: @Barmar I would personally expect a warning like that to appear when you make a table link but don't specify a reference

Comment: @JamesYeoman, why should that be warning? It's throwing a syntax error since logically the syntax is wrong (not as per the documentation). Unless you specify the column name then whom it should refer to???

Comment: @JamesYeoman The issue is that it's using a generic parsing routine. At that stage, it just knows that something is missing.

Comment: Well... thanks guys. I am learning SQL in A-Level Computer Science but they use Microsoft Access. I don't really like being restricted to Microsoft products. It is why I decided to give MySQL a try. Cross-Platform ftw :) anyway, see you